# Good synonym for "professional" that includes skilled amateurs

Tags: synonyms

I sometimes want to stress a technique as something that would be described as *professional*.  In my aviation scenario, I wanted to describe how keeping radio communication parsimonious and brief is just being professional.  (Because you don't want to tie up the frequency for others who are waiting to communicate)

I was unsatisfied with the word choice, however, because I think it's a virtue one should strive for regardless of any world in which pilots are paid to fly. (i.e. professionals and potentially equally-skilled amateurs)  Is there any word that would be useful in such a scenario that implies the same sense of attention to detail and dispassionate pride for a craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who performs a task with meticulous attention to performing it correctly can be said to be *[conscientious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscientious)*.

Comment: Of course!  This I love.  It captures what I'm going for perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In your context, the word "responsible" would fit. However, if you want to describe a person who is highly skilled - without hinting at wages earned - you could use the term "expert".

Comment: I think "expert" stresses skill too much.  I don't think all professionals are experts.  (paid programmers, for instance)  And "responsible" is close, but it feels like to me it hews too far the other way. Presumably all drivers, say, try to be responsible and make sure they don't run out of fuel. But there's a degree above where I'd say a driver who is diligent about keeping separation and being attentive to external variables is being "professional".  Maybe I'm splitting hairs.

Answer (score 0):

keeping radio communication parsimonious and brief is correct procedure.

Or you could say it makes sense.

The sentence would be stronger though (depending on context) if the assignation of virtue (professional, correct, good etc.) was replaced by the actual reason.

Comment: "correct procedure" to me doesn't convey the same sense of doing something out of "professional" pride.  (obviously not the word I want to be using)

Comment: If we work out what is the best way to do things, there's no need for pride. We may attain it, subjectively, with hindsight,  if we let ourselves, but it's not the thing we strive for. We strive to do the right thing. Professionalism is irrelevant.

Comment: If you don't think the phrase "professional pride" is valid, that's fine, but I disagree.  And insofar as it's valid, that's the sense in which I seek a synonym.